# File Upload: File Upload URL not provided

Tags: formio

I've been trying to get file uploads to work, following the instructions for both Dropbox and S3 but each time I just get this message:

> File Upload URL not provided

It doesn't seem to be making any calls to the server. I've found this mention of a bug around file uploads:

https://github.com/formio/ngFormio/issues/322

But I suspect that applies if you're hosting it yourself. I'm using the cloud version.

I've configured it with e.g. the S3 bucket's URL, authentication etc.

What does this error actually mean?

Update: here's the syntax I'm using:

```
<formio form="https://formview.io/#/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/applicationform" url="'https://formview.io/#/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/applicationform'"></formio>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the uploads work, you need to provide the URL of your form, which is used to generate the upload token to upload the files to the 3rd party providers. This can be done in one of two ways.

```
<formio src="'https://examples.form.io/example'"></formio>
```

You would use above if you wish to render the form from the JSON REST API of the form. In many cases, you may wish to provide the actual form object (which I suspect is what you are doing) like so.

```
<formio form="{...}"></formio>
```

This works fine for rendering the form, but it does not provide the URL context for file uploads. For this reason, we have the `url` parameter which you can include along with your form object for file uploads to work.

```
<formio form="{...}" url="'https://examples.form.io/example'"></formio>
```

Providing the url this way is passive. The form will not try to submit to that url, but rather just use it as the url configuration for file uploads.

Comment: Thanks Travis, will make use of this

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again but I've finally come to try this using the snippet I've posted in my question above, and it's still giving me the same behaviour. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I noticed that you are using ```url="'https://formview.io/#/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/applicationform'"``` in your updated code, but it needs to be the API URL in the format of ```https://myproject.form.io/applicationform```.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but still running into problems. Have sent a support request